# Parsing a JSON string in Perl

Tags: json, perl, parsing

We have a device with an API that returns JSON strings. I want to be able to access specific portions of the JSON but I can't figure out how to make the syntax work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use LWP::Simple;
use JSON qw(decode_json);
use Data::Dumper;

my $json_request = 'http://<device ip>/API?method=Display:Input:Status:All:Get';
my $raw_json = get $(json_request)
print($raw_json) 
# Output: {"result":{"0":{"status":false},"1":{"status":false},"2":{"status":false},"3":{"status":false},"4":{"type":"unknown","status":true}},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

I've tried using the JSON library's decode_json function along with Data::Dumper, but here's what I get:

```
print(Dumper(decode_json($raw_json)));
# Output: $VAR1 = { 'jsonrpc' => '2.0', 'result' => { '4' => { 'status' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ), 'type' => 'unknown' }, '1' => { 'status' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ) }, '3' => { 'status' => $VAR1->{'result'}{'1'}{'status'} }, '0' => { 'status' => $VAR1->{'result'}{'1'}{'status'} }, '2' => { 'status' => $VAR1->{'result'}{'1'}{'status'} } } };
```

Not only does this seem to be even more garbled and it doesn't process some of the elements properly, I can't seem to access elements of either that Dumper output or the raw_json variable. I'm admittedly new to Perl but I've tried all of the syntax I can think of and I can't figure it out.

I would like to be able to just have a table with rows 0 through 4 that just says "true" or "false" depending on the entry for that particular JSON element. E.G. for the JSON result here,

```
0: False
1: False
2: False
3: False
4: True
```

Comment: "Not only does this seem to be even more garbled and it doesn't process some of the elements properly" — It looks fine to me. What did you expect? Perl doesn't have a native boolean type, so you get `JSON::PP::Boolean` objects instead … and object property order is not guaranteed in JSON nor is hash key property order guaranteed in Perl.

Comment: "I can't seem to access elements of either that Dumper output or the raw_json variable" — Well, naturally. Both of those are strings. You need to use the output of `decode_json()`

Comment: Quentin okay, so how would I do that?

Comment: https://perlmaven.com/perl-hash

Comment: https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~abatko/computers/programming/perl/howto/hash/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, as far as I can see your JSON contains all the data you want to extract:

```
$ echo '{"result":{"0":{"status":false},"1":{"status":false},"2":{"status":false},"3":{"status":false},"4":{"type":"unknown","status":true}},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' | json_pp 
{
   "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
   "result" : {
      "0" : {
         "status" : false
      },
      "4" : {
         "type" : "unknown",
         "status" : true
      },
      "1" : {
         "status" : false
      },
      "3" : {
         "status" : false
      },
      "2" : {
         "status" : false
      }
   }
}
```

Maybe you have not understood how to access it correctly? The following code seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON qw(decode_json);

my $raw_json = '{"result":{"0":{"status":false},"1":{"status":false},"2":{"status":false},"3":{"status":false},"4":{"type":"unknown","status":true}},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}';
print "${raw_json}\n";

my $object = decode_json($raw_json)
    or die "JSON parse error\n";

my $result = $object->{result};
die "No result object found\n"
    unless $result;

foreach my $key (sort keys %{$result}) {
    print "${key}: ", $result->{$key}->{status} ? "True": "False", "\n";
}

exit 0;
```

Output:

```
{"result":{"0":{"status":false},"1":{"status":false},"2":{"status":false},"3":{"status":false},"4":{"type":"unknown","status":true}},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
0: False
1: False
2: False
3: False
4: True
```